# HLS local http server on iOS8 doesn't work

Tags: http-live-streaming, ios8

I'm creating a local http server to provide http live streaming to a AVPlayer. It works fine on iOS 7, but failed in iOS 8 beta. Player never send request to my local server, its playerItem's status always become AVPlayerStatusFailed right after I call player's 'play' method.

The error I received is as following:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x179c675c0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x17a252c60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12666.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12666), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

I have asked this issue on iOS Developer forum and got response from Apple - "it's due to a bug in the first 8.0 seed".

However, they didn't say that they'll fix this bug and instead asking me why I need to do this. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Can you please share the code that is working for you to stream HLS videos?

Comment: This is Apple's ios 8.0 bug and has been resolved. Thanks!